# SSRS - Empty value

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a parameter `@Destinataire` in SSRS that has a list of values plus an empty string

[image]

I've created a query that I set as available values, which gives me the drop down list

```
SELECT code_name FROM tableA UNION ALL SELECT ''
```

When running the reports with the empty string, I have no results

[image]

I tried to set the parameter as text box and it does not do anything too

Yet when running the sql query I'm using to run this report, things are fine as I have all my rows retrieved (see query below)

```
DECLARE @DateCmt DATE = '05/09/2015',
        @DateFin DATE = '05/09/2016',
        @Restriction INT = 1,
        @Destinataire VARCHAR(5) = ''
        --
        ;

--SELECT @DateCmt,@DateFin

 SELECT DISTINCT 
CFE_EDI.IU_LIASSE
,CFE_EDI.ETAT
,CFE_EDI.DATHRMAJ -- nouveau
,CFE_EDI.ESP_APPLI
,CFE_EDI.NOM_RS
,PARTENAIRES.LIBEL
,PARTENAIRES.CODE_INSEE
,CFE_EDI.DATHR_ENV -- nouveau
,CFE_EDI.DATHR_MEF -- nouveau
,CFE_EDI.DATHR_PRE -- nouveau
,CFE_EDI.DATHR_OUV -- nouveau
--,CFE_EDI.DATEHR_DEPOT-- mettre l'heure
,CFE_EDI.GESTDEL
--,CFE_SERVICE_DEST.IU_DEST
--,CFE_SERVICE.IU_LIASSE
,CASE WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'MEF' THEN 'En Attente le'
     WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'PRE' THEN 'Préparé le' 
     WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'ENV' THEN 'Envoyé le'
     WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'OUV' THEN 'Réceptionné le'
     WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'NRM' THEN 'Non remis le'
     WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'NAQ' THEN 'Non acquitté le'
     END AS ChampEtat
,CASE WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'OUV' THEN 'Date d''envoi : ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CFE_EDI.DATHR_ENV,103)
END AS Date_Envoi,
CASE 
WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT='MEF' THEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR,CFE_EDI.DATHR_MEF,103) 
WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT='PRE' THEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR,CFE_EDI.DATHR_PRE,103) 
WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT='ENV' THEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR,CFE_EDI.DATHR_ENV,103) 
WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT='OUV' THEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR,CFE_EDI.DATHR_OUV,103) 
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,CFE_EDI.DATHR_DEPOT,103) END AS DateMaj ,
CASE
WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT='MEF' then CONVERT(VARCHAR,CFE_EDI.DATHR_MEF,108) 
WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT='PRE' then CONVERT(VARCHAR,CFE_EDI.DATHR_PRE,108) 
WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT='ENV' then CONVERT(VARCHAR,CFE_EDI.DATHR_ENV,108) 
WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT='OUV' then CONVERT(VARCHAR,CFE_EDI.DATHR_OUV,108)
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,CFE_EDI.DATHR_DEPOT,108) END AS HeureMaj,
PARTENAIRES.LIBEL + '(' + CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE + ')' AS LibelDestinataire
--,CASE WHEN @Restriction = 1 THEN '1'
--     WHEN @Restriction = 0 THEN '0' END AS Restriction
,CASE WHEN @DateCmt != @DateFin AND @DateCmt <  @DateFin THEN 'Diffusion Xml du ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,(@DateCmt),103) + ' au ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,(@DateFin),103) ELSE 
'Diffusion EDI Xml du ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@DateCmt,103) END AS Plage_Diffusion
-- INTO 
 FROM   
 (PARTENAIRES 
 INNER JOIN dbo.CFE_EDI ON PARTENAIRES.CODE_INSEE = CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE) 
INNER JOIN dbo.CFE_SERVICE ON CFE_EDI.IU_LIASSE = CFE_SERVICE.IU_LIASSE
INNER JOIN dbo.CFE_SERVICE_DEST ON (PARTENAIRES.IU_PART = CFE_SERVICE_DEST.IU_PART_CFE)
WHERE 
case when @Restriction = 1
              then case when CFE_EDI.ETAT in('ENV','OUV') then 1 else 0 end
           when @Restriction = 0
              then case when CFE_EDI.ETAT not in('ENV','OUV') then 1 else 0 end
           else case when CFE_EDI.ETAT <> '' then 1 else 0 end
       end = 1
AND 
CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE IS NOT NULL AND CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE != '' 
    AND    CASE --WHEN CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE IS NOT NULL AND CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE !=''
           --THEN CASE 
           WHEN @Destinataire != '' AND (@Destinataire) IS NOT NULL
              THEN CASE WHEN CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE = @Destinataire THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           ELSE CASE WHEN CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE = PARTENAIRES.CODE_INSEE 
                    AND cfe_edi.dathrmaj > @DateCmt AND cfe_edi.dathrmaj < @DateFin 
                    AND CFE_EDI.GESTDEL = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  
           END = 1
```

First question would be to know if there is way to setup the parameter without using my stupid trick.

Second question is why the query with parameter with an empty string does the trick and once you use SSRS, nothing.

Thanks in advance for your help

**Update** I tried to set the `WHEN LEN(@Destinataire) > 0` with the `@Destinataire = ''` but no luck on that one.

**Update 2** My aim now is to have a solution that will retrieve all the datas, in case the `@Destinataire` is equal to '' or `NULL`. However, thinking about it, this solution is equivalent to having all the values populated in `@Destinataire`. So one way or another, I would say.

**Final update** I've recreated everything from scratch and oh! magic, the grouping or the everything option worked as wish. I still don't know what was wrong but I'm fine with the results. Many thanks for your help and support.

Comment: Instead of passing an empty string why don't you pass something else "empty" and then either adjust your query or set a case for when the query is passed "empty" set @Destinataire = ''.

Comment: Hi @newGuy nope, your suggestion does not do what it should be supposed to do

Comment: Hi @mike-honey, any chance you can have a look?

Comment: I had a insight when I woke up this evening. Why not use a `len(@Destinataire) > 0`? Let me have a try Monday

Comment: Can you use the value "ALL" rather than empty string then check in your case for Destinaire != 'ALL'

Comment: hi @SteveFord done that already. I've used `Tous` and it did not help.  Albeit, there was still this  `WHEN @Destinataire != '' AND (@Destinataire) IS NOT NULL` at that point. Let me check

Comment: @SteveFord done. Your suggestion retrieve no rows when using ssrs. SQLserver is fine. Maybe it is a ssrs bug ...

Comment: @AndyK may be it's worth writing a report which just shows the value from the parameter so you can debug -- SELECT COALESCE(@Destinaire, 'Null Value').  One further idea is that if your drop down allows multi select then you should be using IN rather than =. If you do allow multiselect you can specify that the default value returns values from a query.

Comment: Not sure how to do this with `Destinataire` with a IN , @steve-ford. Any helps are welcomed

Comment: ping @SteveFord

Comment: Just to clarify the full scenario - is your query above a text query dataset embedded in the report or are we dealing with shared datasets or stored procedures? I assume that the parameter is using your available values query to populate both value field and label field?

Comment: Hi @SMM, it is text query dataset. The parameter is using the available query mentioned in the question. The parameter use a another query (see above too) `SELECT code_name FROM tableA UNION ALL SELECT ''` to populate the drop down list and charge the chosen value to the main query. I hope it all makes sense

Comment: What happens when you run the report if you insert `if @Destinataire ='' raiserror('Destinataire must be set',18,1);` after your declarations?

Comment: @SMM should I put within the report or in the text query?

Comment: In the text query before `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: ok will do @SMM , however I will be able to tell you the results only tomorrow morning as it is 10:09PM CET here. Please put anything you think is relevant and I will have a look

Comment: Perhaps you could add some information to the question about how you are populating the @Destinataire query variable from your report parameter?

Comment: @SMM as said I use a query to produce a list of available values `SELECT code_name FROM tableA UNION ALL SELECT ''`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123256/discussion-between-andy-k-and-smm).

Comment: @AndyK you just use a normal IN (@parm) see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2866/sql-server-reporting-services-using-multivalue-parameters/

Comment: @mike-honey, if you have any hints, I'm all ears. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looking at your query and where you pass @Destinataire you should be able to pass a null value according to the where clause and get the same effect as passing ''

```
 CASE --WHEN CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE IS NOT NULL AND CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE !=''
       --THEN CASE 
       WHEN @Destinataire != '' AND (@Destinataire) IS NOT NULL
          THEN CASE WHEN CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE = @Destinataire THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ELSE CASE WHEN CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE = PARTENAIRES.CODE_INSEE 
                AND cfe_edi.dathrmaj > @DateCmt AND cfe_edi.dathrmaj < @DateFin 
                AND CFE_EDI.GESTDEL = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  
       END = 1
```

I would try to just set that particular paramter to allow nulls in the ssrs report which can be found as a checkbox in your parameter settings window.

Comment: Hi @Zi0n1 the solution you proposed with the NULL is not working too ... Headbanging

Comment: I guess I am not understanding why it has too be a blank space like ''

I would assume that if you even switched it a single space so it is ' ' instead that you might see a positive result. Right now you might be throwing off SSRS because you arent truly passing a value of any kind.

Comment: I even changed my parameter to include `All`then I changed my query to have in the condition `WHEN @Destinataire != '' AND (@Destinataire) IS NOT NULL AND @Destinataire != 'All'`. Even with that, nothing is appearing!!!

Comment: I think I am understanding now. So currently your destinataire paramater would have to be all of those conditions to satisfy the second half of case statement. Try changing those AND's to OR's and also put paranthese around it all like below:
    (WHEN Destinataire != '' OR (Destinataire) IS NOT NULL OR Destinataire != 'All')

Comment: I tried with the parenthesis and then the AND and also the OR and each time, I face the nothing results...

Comment: Hi @Zi0n1, many thanks for your answer. I did not figure out what went wrong so eventually I recreated my report from scratch and the issue was solved by itself.

Answer (score 3):

There is a hybrid option, where you can keep your visible parameter just as you have it, but then use a hidden cascaded parameter to reference in the query.  So if you really are having trouble with formulating your query with blank or null values as a parameter, this will work around that.  Here are the steps:

- Create a new dataset.

A slight catch, you do need to make sure that the changing the selection always adds a new value to force a refresh of the cascaded parameter, but that's easy to do:

```
SELECT code_name FROM tableA WHERE @Destinataire='' OR @Destinataire=code_name
--Dummy value needed to force update of parameter value in some cases:
UNION SELECT 'zz' + @Destinataire AS code_name
```

- Set up a new parameter, `@MultiDestataire`.  Allow it to accept multiple values and use the new dataset as its available and default values.  Set its visibility to Hidden.

Running the report before hiding the new parameter shows how it works:

[image: Parameter Behavior]

- Edit the query to use the new multivalue parameter in its `WHERE` clause.

From here on, this is just altering the query to use the `IN` statement, which should look like this:

```
CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE IS NOT NULL AND CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE != '' 
AND CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE IN (@MultiDestinataire)
...
```

Attempting this may end up being an intermediary step if you've got some other issue in the query that's responsible for unexpected results, as you **should** be able to test for an empty value there.

Comment: Hi @bitnine you gave me some ideas I need to try tomorrow. I'll give you an update.

Comment: Hi @bitnine, as I said to **Zi0n1** , I did not figure out what went wrong so eventually I recreated my report from scratch and the issue was solved by itself. Thanks for being here.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my two cents, basically you have two options here.

**Multivalue parameter Option**

Define your parameter to *allow multivalues*, use the same dataset in `Available values` and `Default values` properties. So when your user doesn't select any value the parameter will be populated with all values. Otherwise your parameter will be populated only with values your users select.

In this case you will have to use `IN` operator since your parameter represent multiple values seleted or not by your user.

```
...
WHERE CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE IN (@Destinataire)
...
```

When you use `Default values` property all drop down list values are selected by default and your report run without any filter being applied (at least if your user doesn't select any value or values).

[image]

Additional, I'd avoid use `''` (blank), it is uninformative and your user might think it is some kind of error or your parameter was not populated properly.

Why use a single value parameters when you want to show data from more than one value (in your case all)?

**Single value Option (No sense IMO)**

In order to this works you have to set your parameter to `Allow blank value ("")` and `Allow null value`. Your query should look like this:

```
WHERE
  CASE WHEN @Destinataire = '' OR @Destinataire is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
  OR
  CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE = @Destinataire
```

In your query I think it could be something like this:

```
WHERE  CASE 
         WHEN @Restriction = 1 THEN 
           CASE 
             WHEN cfe_edi.etat IN( 'ENV', 'OUV' ) THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END 
         WHEN @Restriction = 0 THEN 
           CASE 
             WHEN cfe_edi.etat NOT IN( 'ENV', 'OUV' ) THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END 
         ELSE 
           CASE 
             WHEN cfe_edi.etat <> '' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END 
       END = 1 
       AND cfe_edi.code_insee IS NOT NULL 
       AND cfe_edi.code_insee != '' 
       AND ( CASE 
               --WHEN CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE IS NOT NULL AND CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE !=''  
               --THEN CASE   
               WHEN ( @Destinataire = '' 
                       OR @Destinataire IS NULL ) 
                    AND cfe_edi.code_insee = partenaires.code_insee
                    AND cfe_edi.dathrmaj > @DateCmt 
                    AND cfe_edi.dathrmaj < @DateFin 
                    AND cfe_edi.gestdel = '1' THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
             END = 1 
              OR cfe_edi.code_insee = @Destinataire )
```

Also consider this evaluation `AND cfe_edi.code_insee = partenaires.code_insee`, is it necessary even if your `JOIN` operator is forcing to meet the condition? `INNER JOIN dbo.CFE_EDI ON PARTENAIRES.CODE_INSEE = CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE`

A third option could be use a hidden parameter to clean the `null` and `''` option of the user to produce a parameter populated with all values. Try the options above before get involved with hidden/internal parameter approach.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi @alejandro-zuleta, thanks for your reply. Let's go on a step-by-step basis. Rewriting the `WHERE CASE` did not help. I'm assuming by `Category`, you mean `Destinataire`? 

I would like to use the `IN` operator but if I do that, the option `WHEN ( @Destinataire = '' 
                       OR @Destinataire IS NULL )` will not make sense right? Any feedbacks are more than welcomed as I feel mired

Comment: @AndyK, Category parameter is an example of a multivalue parameter. If you set your parameter as multivalue and use the same dataset (`SELECT code_name FROM tableA`) for available and default values the parameter will be populated by default with all values. Note multivalue parameters include the `Select All` option to automatically select all values, there is no need to use `''` (blank). If you still want to use a single value parameter with `''` option, be sure it is set to `Allow blank value ("")` and `Allow null value`. I've tested the proposed WHERE clause in a basic example and it works.

Comment: why do I have this issue then? Did I do a mistake?

Comment: @AndyK, Does your query return something when you select a value in the parameter?

Comment: Yet it does @alejandro-zuleta but I can't figure what. I tried a `iif(@Destinataire=NULL or @Destinataire='','toto','tata')` in one of my column and I have `tata`. I tried to use a `iif(@Destinataire=NULL or @Destinataire='','toto',ASC(@Destinataire))` and I have `#Error`

Comment: @AndyK, There is no NULL value in SSRS, to test Null values you can try: `IIF(ISNOTHING(Parameters!Destinataire.Value) OR Parameters!Destinataire.Value = "", "toto",ASC(Parameters!Destinataire.Value)`. I suggest you try multivalue parameter approach though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123257/discussion-between-andy-k-and-alejandro-zuleta).

Comment: If I might, there's also a hybrid option.  If you want to keep the same single selection form to the parameter, you can use a hidden cascaded multi-value parameter for the query.  Just set up a new dataset: `SELECT code_name FROM tableA WHERE code_name=@Destinataire OR @Destinataire=''`.  Then create a multivalue parameter (e.g. MultiDestinataire) that uses this dataset as its default values.  And from there modify the query to use `IN (@MultiDestinataire)`.

Comment: Hi @bitnine can you elaborate a bit more, pleasE?

Comment: Certainly.  I've posted the step by step.

Comment: Andy, Did you look at my notes in the discussion? Were any of them helpful?

Comment: Hi @alejandrozuleta your solution did not help me on this one but you've helped me a tremendous deal just by being here and gave me some of your brain power. Many thanks mate , beers are on me if we happen to meet one day. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndyK, you are welcome! I hope if my answer did not help you, it gave you a basic understanding about SSRS parameters. It is hard to reproduce issues in SSRS mainly because there is no datasource in most cases. I am glad you managed to solve it.

Comment: It did @alejandrozuleta . I learnt a tremendous deal about parameters. Not sure how relevant it is now but in the near future, it will help. I've never been stuck for so long on an issue but I don't give up :)